# "Which of those is your cousin?" or "Whom of those is your cousin?"

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

Which of the following sentences is correct, and why?

> 1. **Which** of those is your cousin?
> 2. **Whom** of those is your cousin?

More generally, do we say "**Which** of those people?" or "**Whom** of those people?"

Comment: Which of those people?? Whom of those people??

Comment: *which* . *Whom* won't work because it's not the object of a preposition.

Comment: In your sentences, "which" and "whom" are not relative pronouns, but interrogative pronouns.

Comment: "Which" or "Who" will work here, but whom won't as it's told you before. See here how to use "whom" in questions: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/who-or-whom

Answer (score 2):

I would say, *who* of those is your cousin (not "whom"; whom is for the object of the sentence, and "cousin" is the subject, not the object).

*Which of those* is also correct.

In the future, you might want to post these questions on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'd say 'Which of those ...' is by far the more idiomatic when a smallish set of candidates is involved (and that is almost certainly the case here) and there is a single-member answer. 'Who of those can we possibly trust?', with an unknown size of answer, sounds better to my ears.